# Nuget Packages with content in ASP.net 5

Tags: asp.net, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a couple packages that include content files (an example would be the wurfl package for getting device data from a user agent, it includes it's database file in the nuget package marked as content).

When adding these packages in an asp.net 5 setting, the content doesn't get added anywhere.

Where or how do I get at the content of these nuget packages added to my solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://blog.nuget.org/20150729/Introducing-nuget-uwp.html

> Deprecated Features
>
> Starting with NuGet 3.1 when using project.json, we are deprecating support for executing the install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 scripts and **delivering elements in the /content folder of packages**. Installing packages that have these elements will not execute the install.ps1 file and **will not copy content to your project**.

Read the link for more on why...

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll try some embedded resource trickery or something

Comment: next version of asp.net will be going back to msbuild and project.json will be removed. Is that mean we will start using those functionaries ?
Articles :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/12/The-Future-of-project-json-in-ASP-NET-Core

Comment: @MuratMercan - who knows, guess we'll find out.

Answer (score 0):

Include a YourPacakgeName.targets file in your package like this:

```
<file src="YourPacakgeName.targets" target="build" />
```

The content of the .targets file should then be:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\Content\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <Copy
      SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\%(RecursiveDir)"
      SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Effectively this copies the content files before a build and after a clean action.